# Do I need a unit test constructor?

Tags: nunit

I have projects set up as follows:

1. Data - repository.
2. Service
3. Web

I'm using NUnit, and I'm testing a method that is in `Service` Project. When I first used MSTest to automatically setup these tests for me, it created a unit test constructor that looks like this:

```
    Service service;
    [Test]
    public void ServiceConstructorTest()
    {
        IRepository repository = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        service = new Service(repository );
        Assert.Inconclusive("TODO: Implement code to verify target");
    }
```

When I try to test a method, this constructor is not executed and `service` ends up being null. Am I going to have to declare and mock every time I write a test?

Comment: the code you are showing is not a constructor, but I think I know what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NUnit has a [SetUp] attribute that you put on a method, and that method will be called before each test is executed.  There is also a [TearDown] attribute that causes the method to be run after each unit test as well.